# Swift Vapor Postgres Xcode Build Error: Could not build Objective-C module 'CPostgreSQLMac'

Tags: swift, xcode, postgresql, vapor

There is a build error after adding the vapor postgresql connector to Package.swift

```
    import PackageDescription

        let package = Package(
        name: "todo_vapor_swift",
            dependencies: [
                .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 5),
                .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/postgresql-provider", majorVersion: 1, minor: 0)
],
exclude: [
    "Config",
    "Database",
    "Localization",
    "Public",
    "Resources",
]
```

)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps you installed postgress with Postgress.app or another way. You need to install using brew to resolve this error.

Run the following: `brew install postgres`

Comment: Thanks for posting this!